# Firefox cannot open Google (sec_error_unknown_issuer)

Tags: windows, firefox, exception, certificate

I am trying to fix the following issue.

On a **Windows 7** machine, I installed the latest version of **Firefox (40.0.3)**. However, when I try to open **https://www.google.ch**, I get the following error:

> sec_error_unknown_issuer.

There is NO button that says

> I understand the risks

Other sites, like **youtube (using HTTPS)**, load without errors.

I already deleted the cert8.db file, and the date and time of the machine are also correct.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open this chrome URI by pasting or typing this URI in the location/address bar to open the "Add Security Exception" window and check the certificate:

chrome://pippki/content/exceptionDialog.xul
In the location field type/paste the URL of the website

retrieve the certificate via the "Get certificate" button
inspect the certificate via the "View..." button